# Separate objects to two groups in Angular.JS - ng-hide vs filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a object with data what i want separate and show in two lists. Object looks for example that:

```
var data = [
   {name: "Something 1", active: 1, datetime: "goes", author: "here"},
   {name: "Something 2", active: 0, datetime: "goes", author: "here"},
   {name: "Something 3", active: 0, datetime: "goes", author: "here"}
];
```

As you might guess, I want separate active and inactive data. What's better to do that?

Filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="out in data | filter:{'active':1}">{{out.name}}</li>
```

Or maybe ng-hide (for inactive):

```
<li ng-repeat="out in data" ng-hide="out.active">{{out.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need inactive element to be on the DOM tree?

If not, use ng-if, this way you won't load unecessary HTML to your document.

Comment: <li ng-if="data.active">{{out.name}}</li>